# SSRS vertical merge

Tags: reporting-services, merge, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I need to vertically merge cells in SSRS, but only in certain situations.  I have a record set that looks like this:

```
    ID    Name      #Times Changed
     1     John       2
     1     John       2
     3     Steve      1
     4     Tom        1
```

In this situation I only want John to have a vertically merged cell that displays the number 2.

I understand that you can't really vertically merge cells in SSRS, but does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: So instead of showing John 2 twice you just want to show it once?

Comment: Yes.  There would be one box showing a "2" for #Times Changed for John.

Comment: If I saw that data I'd assume that the were duplicates in my data.

Comment: There are no duplicates.  There can be two records for John, each with a different timestamp.  The #Times Changed column counts the number of times an agent made a change to the record in the system.  One update could be on 06/14 10:02:34 and another could be 06/14 10:05:23.

Comment: Group on times changed and ID in a single parent group. make John  the details column and then include the timestamp to get both Johns

Comment: That's actually close to what I'm looking for.  The column is now on the far left of the table.  Is there a way to move the column to another part of the table?  If I cut and paste the column loses the vertical merge.

Comment: Make a column to the right that has the same value as the one on the left then make the left invisible.

Comment: I added the columns to the left and right and then deleted the original columns.  It looks great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I figured out how to vertically merge the cells:

I did a single parent grouping on timeschanged and ID and a Details grouping on datechangedon.  This created a vertically merged cell, but placed the cell on the far left.  I needed the merged cell somewhere in the middle of the report.  If I attempted to place a column to the left of the merged cell, then that column also became merged since it is now part of the grouping.  To overcome this I put a new tablix into every column on the left part of the merged cell, and put the appropriate column into each tablix.  The image below is a clip of the final table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe
you can do this by adding a parent group to the table